# ExtJS using CheckboxSelectionModel to select multiple rows

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to ExtJS, the version is 3.4.0.
Now what I want to do is when I select one row, all the other rows which have the same ''actionId'' will be selected too. Any ideas?
Here is part of my code

```js
var xg = Ext.grid;
var checkboxSelector = new xg.CheckboxSelectionModel({
  header: '',
  handleMouseDown: Ext.emptyFn,
  listeners: {
    'rowselect': function(selectionModel, rowIndex, record) {
      var valueSelected = record.get('actionId');
    }
  }
});
var erroneousActionsGrid = new xg.GridPanel({
      id: 'erroneousActionsPanel',
      layout: 'fit',
      store: store,
      cm: new xg.ColumnModel([
        checkboxSelector, {
          header: "Action Name",
          width: 80,
          sortable: true,
          dataIndex: 'actionName'
        }, {
          header: "Action Id",
          width: 30,
          sortable: true,
          dataIndex: 'actionId'
        }, {
          id: 'files',
          header: "File Id",
          width: 30,
          sortable: true,
          dataIndex: 'fileId',
          renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            return '<a href=file/lifeCycleFile/' + value + '>' + value + '</a>';
          }
        }, {
          header: "Task Id",
          width: 30,
          sortable: true,
          dataIndex: 'taskId'
        }, {
          header: "User Name",
          width: 50,
          sortable: true,
          dataIndex: 'userName'
        }, {
          header: "Execute Date",
          width: 30,
          sortable: true,
          dataIndex: 'executeDate',
          renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y/m/d H:i:s')
        }
      ]),
      bbar: actionListPagingBar,
      plugins: [{
        ptype: 'perpagefield',
        beforeText: ''
      }],
      sm: checkboxSelector,
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So in your rowselect handler you now have the value you require. From here you need to search your store for records with matching field values, there are methods on the store that will allow you to do this and return an array of matched records.

You can then set the selections on your selection model object. Again there is a function to do this which takes an array of records which you would have retrieved from your store search as above. You may need to add multiSelect:true to your selection model config too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mindparse :) It helps me a lot!